# Browse & recover specific files from Windows 10 image backup?

Tags: windows-10, backup

I have a Windows 10 image backup from about 6 months ago that contains some code I need to recover.

The image backup was made on my prior PC, which has since suffered a catastrophic hard drive failure and was reimaged with Windows 10.

Is it possible to browse the old image backup and find and extract the folder(s) I need?

Answer (score 0):

Simple, but ridiculously hard to find with Google if you don't know what to search for.

1. There are .vhdx files in the WindowsImageBackup folder
2. Find the .vhdx that represents the disk you want to mount/explore
3. Attach the .vhdx with diskpart or Disk Management
4. Assign a drive letter
5. Browse with File Explorer

Caveat: You might have to open a DOS cmd prompt in Admin mode and use diskpart to assign the drive a letter.

[image: diskpart in Admin cmd window]